# Continuous Bijection which is Not a Homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, functions

The problem is: given $A = (0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$, find a set $B \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and a function $g: A \longrightarrow B$ which is a continuous bijection but not a homeomorphism.

So I know that in order for $g$ not to be a homeomorphism, its inverse must not be continuous. I have seen a similar example of a function $f: (0,1] \longrightarrow S^1$ which not a homeomorphism since $f^{-1}$ is not continuous at $(1,0).$ However, if the domain of $f$ were instead $(0,1)$ it would be a homeomorphism, so I'm not sure how (or if) $S^1$ would work in the problem for the codomain of $g$.

I've looked at the answers to the other questions on Math.SE pertaining to examples of non-homeomorphic continuous bijections but none have seemed to help, e.g. the domain is usually more like $(0,1]$ than $(0,0)$.

Comment: Hint: you have a copy of (0,1] inside (0,1) in the form of (0,1/2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a figure eight space, e.g. map $(0,\tfrac12]$ to the circle centered at $(0,1)$ with radius $1$ and map $[\tfrac12,1)$ to the circle centered at $(0,-1)$ likewise with radius $1$ and in both cases with $\tfrac12$ mapping to the origin.  Then "glue" the maps together to get one continuous bijection from $(0,1)$ to the figure eight.  It won't have a continuous inverse because a figure eight minus one point (with one obvious exception) will be connected, but $(0,1)$ minus one point isn't connected.

Such a map is an example of an [immersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immersion_(mathematics)).

Answer (score 1):

Define $g$ such that

- when $t$ goes from $0$ to $\frac14$, $g(t)$ goes in a straight line from $(0,3)$ to $(0,0)$;
- when $t$ goes from $\frac14$ to $\frac12$, $g(t)$ goes in a straight line from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$;
- when $t$ goes from $\frac12$ to $\frac34$, $g(t)$ goes in a straight line from $(1,0)$ to $(1,2)$;
- when $t$ goes from $\frac34$ to $1$,$$g(t)=\left(4-4t,2+\sin\left(\frac\pi{4-4t}\right)\right).$$

Then $g$ is not a homeomorphism, since $(0,1)$ is not homeomorphic to $g\bigl((0,1)\bigr)$:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$g(x)=\begin{cases}
(6x-2,0)&\text{ if }0\lt x\le\frac12,\\
(\cos(2x-1)\pi,\sin(2x-1)\pi)&\text{ if }\frac12\le x\lt1.\\
\end{cases}$